# How to set different lines on a JTextPane?

Tags: java, arrays, swing, jtextpane

so say I have this `JTextPane`:

```
JTextPane list = new JTextPane();
list.setEditable(false);
```

and I have the following array of strings:

```
        String[] pop;
        List<String>popp = new ArrayList<>();
        for(String c : Main.population){
            popp.add(c);
        }
        pop = new String[popp.size()];
        int i = 0;
        for(String e : popp){
            pop[i] = e;
            i++;
        }
```

and I want to display the array of strings on the JTextPane:

```
  list.setText(pop[0] +  pop[1] + pop[2]);
```

this will display the strings in a line and when there is no more space in the next line.

How can i make it so every string is in a separate line of the JTextPane?

Answer (score 4):

You can make use of a `StringJoiner` set to use `\n` for new lines, for example

```
String[] pop = ...;
StringJoiner joiner = new StringJoiner("\n");
for (String text : pop) {
    joiner.add(text);
}
```

And then just use

```
list.setText(joiner.toString());
```

Comment: thanks i will accepted as soon as i can. I have another question how can "pack" the JTextPane(when all the text is added set the size of the JtextPane based on the ammount of lines)?

Comment: You can't, not really.  The `preferredSize` should calculate out so that it's width and height meets the minimum requirements of the text, so you really don't need to do anything on that front per say

Comment: Just a small precision: I think that the preferredSize uses the current width and evaluate height required by the text.

Comment: @Sharcoux If that was so, then the text should wrap, but it doesn't, it will continue until a line break is meet

Comment: Text wraps in JTP. Try http://pastebin.com/TvNwaC6u with Java 7. Actually, we're both right : getPreferredSize() returns the width of the longest text line with no break, and the height the text would have if it wrapped given the current width.

Comment: @Sharcoux  There is going to be a difference between what the component's `prefferredSize` returns and how it handles instances when the available space is smaller then it wants, in this case, it wraps the text, that's my point.  Try leaving the layout set as `BorderLayout` and using `mainFrame.pack()` after you've added the `JTextPane`.  The `preferredSize` is calculated by the determining the longest line and the number rows, if a layout/container choose to ignore those, the `JTextPane` will try to compensate, which means wrapping the lines and running the rows off the end

Comment: I don't agree. `mainFrame.pack()` just uses the info returned by the JTextPane `preferredSize`. If the width of JTP is 0, then the `preferredSize` returns what you say, but if the width is higher, then the width is the unwrapped size, and the height is the wrapped one, whatever the layout. Try to add `jtp.setSize(300,jtp.getPreferredSize().height);` before the `pack()`

Comment: @Sharcoux This is my point.  If you packed the frame, it's the `preferredSize` of the `JTextPane` which is going to influence the size of the widnow

Comment: @Sharcoux So, using your code as a base, if I remove `setLayout(null)` and `pack` the frame after adding the `JTextPane`, the size of the frame is `java.awt.Dimension[width=3482,height=60]`.  The `JTextPane` is calculating it's `preferredSize` based on the requirements of the longest line (width) and the number of lines/rows (height) (and some font measurements). If you try and place the `JTextPane` into a smaller area, it will automatically wrap the text, but that has nothing to do with how the `preferredSize` is calculated

Comment: Again, just before the `pack()`, add `jtp.setSize(300,jtp.getPreferredSize().height);`, or `jtp.setSize(300,10);`. You will see that the size of the window is far higher than the text.

Comment: @Sharcoux Okay, so it's contextual.  This is what I understand.  If the size of the `JTextComponent` is `0x0`, it's `preferredSize` is calculated based on the text, if it's not (ie having had `setSize` called upon it), then it's `preferredSize` is calculated based on available space of the component.  (`BasicTextUI#getPreferredSize`).

Answer (score 2):

You need to add a newline character between each line:

```
list.setText(pop[0] + "\n" + pop[1] + "\n" + pop[2]);
```

Or the better approach is to just update the `Document` directly:

```
Document doc = textPane.getDocument();

for (String text: pop)
    doc.insertString(pop[0] + "\n", doc.getLength(), null);
```

There is no need to create the `String` containing all the text first. This will take more memory. Adding one line at a time allows you to add any number of lines.

This approach is essentially what the `JTextArea.append(...)` method does.

Answer (score 0):

The `\n` escape character in java would allow you to separate lines. So you could add that character for every element in the array.

```
 pop[i] = e + "\n";
```

Answer (score 0):

In Java 8, you can do :

```
list.setText(String.join("\n",pop));
```